# Running pom.xml fails on an Apache project-James

Tags: pom.xml, james

I am getting error

```
 Failed to execute goal on project james-server: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.james:james-server:jar:2.3.2: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:129 (compile), org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14-workaround:jar:129 (compile),
```

Here is pom.xml in Apache James project which i downloaded with source:

```
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
  software distributed under the License is distributed on an
  "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
  KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
  specific language governing permissions and limitations
  under the License.    
-->
<!--
 | DISCLAIMER DISCLAIMER DISCLAIMER DISCLAIMER DISCLAIMER 
 | 
 | This file is only intended to be used to build the james-server
 | website. It must not be used to build packages for james-server
 | application.
 | 
 | DISCLAIMER DISCLAIMER DISCLAIMER DISCLAIMER DISCLAIMER 
 -->
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
  <artifactId>james-server</artifactId>
  <name>Apache JAMES Server</name>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <description>
    The Apache Java Enterprise Mail Server (a.k.a. JAMES Server)
  </description>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>james-server-root</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <relativePath>../james-project/project/server/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <url>http://james.apache.org/server/2.3.2/</url>
  <inceptionYear>2002</inceptionYear>

  <scm>
    <connection>
      scm:svn:http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/james/server/tags/2_3_2
    </connection>
    <developerConnection>
      scm:svn:https://${maven.username}@svn.apache.org/repos/asf/james/server/tags/2_3_2
    </developerConnection>
    <url>
      http://svn.apache.org/viewcvs.cgi/james/server/tags/2_3_2?root=Apache-SVN
    </url>
  </scm>

  <repositories>
    <!-- 
     this should be removed and custom jars should 
     be copied to a local files based repository.
    -->
    <repository>
      <id>bago-dist-m1</id>
      <name>Temporary Repository</name>
      <url>http://people.apache.org/~bago/maven/dist-m1</url>
      <layout>legacy</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Apache Snapshot Repository</name>
      <url>http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-ibiblio-rsync-repository</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
      <id>apache.snapshots</id>
      <name>Apache Snapshot Repository</name>
      <url>http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>

<!-- 
    <repository>
      <id>local-server-3rd-party-m1</id>
      <name>Local Server third party repository</name>
      <url>file://${basedir}/repos/third-party-m1</url>
      <layout>legacy</layout>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
 -->

    <repository>
      <id>ibiblio</id>
      <name>Main maven repo</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>

  </repositories>

  <dependencies verbose="true">

    <!-- NEED TO DEAL WITH THESE JARS -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
      <version>129</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14-workaround</artifactId>
      <version>129</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- NEED TO DEAL WITH THESE JARS -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
      <artifactId>avalon-framework-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
      <artifactId>avalon-framework-impl</artifactId>
      <version>4.3</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>jmock</groupId>
          <artifactId>jmock</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>xalan</groupId>
          <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
          <artifactId>xmlParserAPIs</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>xerces</groupId>
          <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>cornerstone-connection</groupId>
      <artifactId>cornerstone-connection-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>cornerstone-connection</groupId>
      <artifactId>cornerstone-connection-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>cornerstone-sockets</groupId>
      <artifactId>cornerstone-sockets-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>cornerstone-sockets</groupId>
      <artifactId>cornerstone-sockets-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
          <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>cornerstone-datasources</groupId>
      <artifactId>cornerstone-datasources-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>excalibur-datasource</groupId>
      <artifactId>excalibur-datasource</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>excalibur-pool</groupId>
          <artifactId>excalibur-pool-instrumented</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>excalibur-component</groupId>
          <artifactId>excalibur-component</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>excalibur-component</groupId>
          <artifactId>excalibur-testcase</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>excalibur-fortress</groupId>
          <artifactId>excalibur-fortress</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>excalibur-fortress</groupId>
          <artifactId>excalibur-fortress-container-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>excalibur-logger</groupId>
          <artifactId>excalibur-logger</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
          <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>excalibur-fortress</groupId>
          <artifactId>excalibur-fortress-meta</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>cornerstone-datasources</groupId>
      <artifactId>cornerstone-datasources-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>d-haven-managed-pool</groupId>
          <artifactId>d-haven-managed-pool</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>cornerstone-scheduler</groupId>
      <artifactId>cornerstone-scheduler-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>cornerstone-scheduler</groupId>
      <artifactId>cornerstone-scheduler-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>cornerstone-store</groupId>
      <artifactId>cornerstone-store-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>cornerstone-store</groupId>
      <artifactId>cornerstone-store-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>dnsjava</groupId>
      <artifactId>dnsjava</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>excalibur-thread</groupId>
      <artifactId>excalibur-thread-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>excalibur-thread</groupId>
      <artifactId>excalibur-thread-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>junitperf</groupId>
          <artifactId>junitperf</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>avalon-logkit</groupId>
      <artifactId>avalon-logkit</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>geronimo-spec</groupId>
          <artifactId>geronimo-spec-javamail</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>geronimo-spec</groupId>
          <artifactId>geronimo-spec-jms</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>servletapi</groupId>
          <artifactId>servletapi</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>oro</groupId>
      <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <distributionManagement>
    <site>
      <id>server-2.3.2-website</id>
      <url>scp://people.apache.org/www/james.apache.org/server/2.3.2/</url>
    </site>
  </distributionManagement>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>

    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/test</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.zone</include>
        </includes>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <optimize>true</optimize>
          <source>1.4</source>
          <target>1.4</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>

  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <!-- Removed because it seems to have bugs.
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-report-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxr-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <targetjdk>1.4</targetjdk>
          <rulesets>
            <ruleset>/rulesets/basic.xml</ruleset>
            <ruleset>/rulesets/controversial.xml</ruleset>
          </rulesets>
          <format>xml</format>
          <linkXref>true</linkXref>
          <sourceEncoding>utf-8</sourceEncoding>
          <minimumTokens>100</minimumTokens>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!--
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>taglist-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>

</project>
```

I am new to maven and pom please specify a path on how should i change my pom.xml

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

goal must be `eclipse:eclipse`

my goal was `dependency:copy-dependencies`